# SQL getting member count from join table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add field to my entity called memberCount while getting multiple data here's my query below

```
communityRepository.createQueryBuilder("community")                    
    .loadRelationCountAndMap('community.member_count', 'community.members')
    .where("community.community_type = :type", {type: "public"})
    .orWhere("community.communityId IN (SELECT uc.community_id FROM user_community uc WHERE uc.user_id = :userId)", {userId: paginationDTO.id})
    .orderBy("community.communityName")
    .skip(paginationDTO.page * paginationDTO.limit)
    .take(paginationDTO.limit).getMany()
```

but it throws error

> "message": "Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '57694a5a580f9cc5063b3dc0' to data type int."

my community id is nvarchar and my user_id is int

community.member tables structure is like

```
community_id | user_id

xyz          | 1
xyz          | 2
```

Comment: Can you see the generated SQL query?

Comment: What columns in ``user_community``? And type of ``paginationDTO.id``

Comment: What do you expect as an answer here? Nobody can see your screen, we don't know what your tables definitions are, we don't know what your actual query is. Essentially you posted some code with no details and asked why it doesn't work. Help us to help you by providing enough information so that others can actually help.